# Съезжает картинка на сайте при редактировании кода css

Tags: html, css

Нужно вставить картинку лампочки справа вниз под текст, но она почему-то съезжает с main в footer...

```css
body {
  background: #f9e933;
}

header,
main,
footer {
  min-width: 855px;
}

header.container,
main.container,
footer.container {
  max-width: 855px;
  margin: auto;
}

header {
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}

header h1 {
  float: left;
  width: 570px;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  width: 285px;
}

main {
  background: white;
}

.img {
  width: 285px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
  clear: right;
}

.maintext {
  float: left;
  width: 570px;
}

.contact {
  float: left;
  width: 570px;
}

.sitemap {
  float: right;
  width: 285px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Amazeriffic</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Amazeriffic!</h1>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">Регистрация</a> |
        <a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a> |
        <a href="#">Техподдержка</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main_text">
        <h2>Amazerific это будущее!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        <h3>Почему вам нужен Amazeriffic?</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Это наше с вами будущее</li>
          <li>Вместе мы выйдем на новый уровень жизни</li>
          <li>Мы построим богатое и счастливое общество</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="img">
        <img src="lightbulb.png" alt="Изображение лампочки">
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="contact">
        <h4>Свяжитесь с нами</h4>
        <p>Amazeriffic!</p>
        <p>мкр.Московский д.14, 153048</p>
        <p>Иваново, Россия</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sitemap">
        <h5>Карта сайта</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"> На главную страницу <a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#"> О компаснии </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Техроддержка </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Вакансии </a></li>
          <li><a href="FAQ.html"> FAQ </a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Конфиденциальность </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы слишком увлеклись в стилях свойством `float`. Из-за такого массового обтекания у Вас изображение лампочки смещается даже не в footer, а под footer, так как он у Вас нулевой высоты, обратите внимание. На будущее, когда Вы будете размещать контент на странице в несколько колонок, то воспользуйтесь `flexbox`. И все остальные элементы будет выстраивать куда проще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Amazeriffic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header__wrap">
            <h1 class="header__title">Amazeriffic!</h1>
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav__item" href="#">Регистрация</a>
                <a class="nav__item" href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
                <a class="nav__item" href="#">Техподдержка</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<main class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main__wrap">
            <h2>Amazerific это будущее!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <h3>Почему вам нужен Amazeriffic?</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Это наше с вами будущее</li>
                <li>Вместе мы выйдем на новый уровень жизни</li>
                <li>Мы построим богатое и счастливое общество</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="img">
            <img class="img__item" src="https://superawesomevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/flat-light-bulb-vector-800x566.jpg" alt="Изображение лампочки">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="footer__wrap">
            <div class="contact">
                <h4>Свяжитесь с нами</h4>
                <p>Amazeriffic!</p>
                <p>мкр.Московский д.14, 153048</p>
                <p>Иваново, Россия</p>
            </div>
            <div class="sitemap">
                <h5>Карта сайта</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> На главную страницу</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> О компаснии</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> Техроддержка</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> Вакансии</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="FAQ.html"> FAQ</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"> Конфиденциальность</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    background: #f9e933;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1440px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer__wrap,
.header__wrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__title {
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.header,
.main {
    background: white;
}

.nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.nav__item {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.nav__item:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.img__item {
    width: 285px;
    height: auto;
}
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/tsezhk31/1/) с использованием [Flex](https://basicweb.ru/css/css_pr_flex.php)